# Email not receiving in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have my email set up in development and it works perfectly:

```
# Don't care if the mailer can't send.
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
     :authentication => :plain,
     :address => "smtp.mailgun.org",
     :port => 587,
     :domain => "somedomain.co",
     :user_name => "postmaster@somedomain.co",
     :password => "password"
  }
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
```

And in production:

```
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
     :authentication => :plain,
     :address => "smtp.mailgun.org",
     :port => 587,
     :domain => "somedomain.co",
     :user_name => "postmaster@somedomain.co",
     :password => "password"
  }
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { protocol: 'https', host: 'nestie.co' }
```

But in production I don't receive any email.

Does something look terribly incorrect to you? 
I'm not sure whats going on...

Comment: Have you looked in your development and production logs for clues?

Comment: I'd love too but I'm not sure how I can do this. I usually use Heroku and can check the logs with `heroku logs` but this application is using another service, probably AWS

Comment: I was referring to the  `./log/development.log` and `./log/production.log` inside your project. I would also set `config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true` and see what pops out. P.S. what version of Rails/ AM?

Answer (score 0):

go to following link and turn on https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps